# What programs have host countries of refugee implemented in the past to help refugees?

Tags: armed-conflict, refugees

There has been an increase in refugee numbers recently, doubling from roughly 10 million people in 2010 to roughly 20 million people in 2020 ([Source](https://www.unhcr.org/flagship-reports/globaltrends/)). I am assuming that the majority of the recent increment could be attributed to the Syrian civil war, and very recently Ukraine-Russian war (2020 statistics do not account for the recent Ukraine-Russian war, but I'm certain there are many refugees resulting from this war as well).

What kind of programs/initiatives have host countries undertaken to help these refugees? I'm primarily interested in the host countries that has been hosting many of these refugees (eg. Turkey), but I'll also be interested to see other countries' program if they are notable. It would be great if the answer could also include an analysis of the effectiveness of these programs, but that is just an extension of the question and not necessarily the main question.

While I am not most knowledgable about different programs for refugees, some examples could be: Easing refugee application process, or implementing an assimilation program to help them find a job in the host country, etc.

Comment: Hosting refugees is itself a help to refugees.  What sort of programs do you have in mind?  Different countries will have different programs; for starters, their basic refugee systems can vary from keeping thousands of them in a huge camp to dispersing them in small numbers to communities around the country and giving them support for housing and employment.

Comment: I have added some examples. I'm not knowledgable enough in this regard to give solid examples, hence this question, but I'm up for any initiatives/programs that help refugees (short-term issues like actually escaping their country and getting into the host country, finding housing/food; long-term issues like education for children, job opportunities for adults).